# Как использовать даные из двух связаных таблиц

Tags: php, yii2

Есть две таблицы:

```
serial=>id, name_serial, created_at;
films=>id, name_films, created_at,id_serial;
```

Таблицы связаны друг другом в моделях, причем **serial** связана ещё и с моделью **image**

**Serial:**

```
public function getFilms(){
        return $this->hasMany(Films::className(),['id_serial'=>'id']);
    }
public function getImages(){
        return $this->hasMany(Image::className(), [ 'id_serial'=>'id' ]);
    }
```

**Films:**

```
public function getSerial()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Serial::className(), ['id'=>'id_serial']);
}
```

Мне надо вывести по дате (`created_at`) данные с  обоих таблиц причем так, что бы я смог потом использовать связи к примеру что бы при выводе `Film` 
я мог потом получить `Image` у `Serial` вот так `$films->serial->images` и s`erial->image serial->films`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$films = Films::find()->orderBy(['created_at' => SORT_DESC])->all();
```

аналогично с сериалами